# RewriteRule : How can i handle my url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need Rewrite code for my `.httaccess` file where i can froward my url to specific folder default page.

LIKE if the following url not found:

> www.domain.com/abc/23/121/     >>>  www.domain.com/abc/default.php

OR

> www.domain.com/xyz/23/121/     >>>  www.domain.com/xyz/default.php

What ever first folder, it will redirect to its folder default file.

How can I forward URL by `.httaccess` to any error handler file?

> www.domain.com/xyz/23/121/

when this url not found.. It will take compeler url as query string to `404.php`

Like :

> 404.php?url=www.domain.com/xyz/23/121/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /404.php?url=$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Comment: @Starkeen Current Apach have command for this purpose: `FallbackResource /404.php`